# Using the same controller from a modal and in stand alone with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the same controller from a modal (dialog : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ) and in stand alone. But I do not know how to do that

```
'use strict';

App.controller "ApplicationNewCtrl", ["$scope", "dialog", "Application", "$window", ($scope, dialog, Application, $window) ->
  $scope.application = new Application()

  $scope.create = ($event, application) ->
    $event.preventDefault()

    $scope.application.$save (result) ->
      if dialog.isOpen()
        dialog.close()
      else
        $window.location.href = "/applications/#{$scope.application.id}"

  $scope.close = (result) ->
    dialog.close(result)

]
```

So, the "dialog" is injected in my controller when I use a modal but when I use this from my router (stand alone) :

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider' ,
($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
  #$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode true
  # Applications
  $routeProvider.when("/applications/new",
    templateUrl: '/applications/new.html?l=false'
  )
])
```

I have this error :

> Error: Unknown provider: dialogProvider <- dialog

How can I do to manage dynamically inkections? I tried to remove the "dialog" injection and replace it per $injector.get('dialog') but it does not work

Comment: your problem here is that you're using an instance of a service instead of a provider. `dialog` service wasn't defined using a provider. in any case, I don't really know how to reuse that easily

Comment: ok, do you have any advice to know how to do it?